# trouble with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I try to load data from file with XMLHttpRequest.
Check all spalling, it seems ok.

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var count=0;

var server = new http.Server(function(req, res){

console.log(req.url);
res.write("Request  " + (++count) + " ");

if (req.url=='/23801'){

    res.statusCode=200;
    res.end("Page Found ");
    readFile();
} else {
    console.log("missed");
    res.statusCode=404;
    res.end("Page not found");
}

})
server.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');


function readFile() {

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var fileName = "company.json";
console.log(fileName);
xhr.open('GET', fileName, false);
xhr.send();
if (xhr.status != 200) {

    alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText); 
} else {

    alert(xhr.responseText); 
}

}
```

And when i try to loas localhost:8080/23801

i recieve error like this:

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

```
          ^
```

ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined

What i do wrong?
I serch similar topics, but didnt find correct decision.

Comment: Node and JavaScript are used for different purposes.

Comment: If you are running `readFile()` in node, `XMLHttpRequest` doesn't exist there

Comment: that object is part of the DOM api, which isn't javascript, and isn't available to node. There are modules that replicate it for node, but with node there are better options than that.

Comment: Have a look at the [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/fs.html) module for node

Comment: Sorry for stupid question and thanks for right dirrection.